# Is changing WebRootFileProvider a proper way to apply custom IFileProvider to asp-append-version? Any side-effect?

Tags: file, asp.net-core, static-files, asp.net-core-staticfile

I want to be able to serve files with a custom file path (`js/v1/foo.js` can be mapped to a real file at `wwwroot/js/foo.js`). I created `VersionedFileProvider` which could map that already. I set it like this:

```
        app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
        {
            FileProvider = new CompositeFileProvider(
                new VersionedFileProvider(env.WebRootPath),
                env.WebRootFileProvider),
        });
```

All files are working. However, if I use that custom path, `asp-append-version` does not work. When I check the [source code](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/4e44025a52e4b73aa17e09a8041b0e166e0c5ce0/src/Mvc/Mvc.Razor/src/Infrastructure/DefaultFileVersionProvider.cs), they are taking `WebRootFileProvider` instead of the one I am setting in `UseStaticFiles`.

Luckily, `env.WebRootFileProvider` is settable, so I can resolve the problem with:

```
        env.WebRootFileProvider = new CompositeFileProvider(
            new VersionedFileProvider(env.WebRootPath),
            env.WebRootFileProvider);
        app.UseStaticFiles();
```

However, I have to admit I do not know what else is using `WebRootFileProvider` and what side-effect can possibly happen. Please help me confirm this is a proper way to resolve my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Confirm from development team the way I suggested in the question is recommended](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/17409#issuecomment-558744075)

```
    env.WebRootFileProvider = new CompositeFileProvider(
        new VersionedFileProvider(env.WebRootPath),
        env.WebRootFileProvider);
    app.UseStaticFiles();
```